# Magento PayPal Requested and configured merchant emails do not match

Tags: magento, paypal

Magento is periodically logging the following error.

> ERR (3): exception 'Exception' with message 'Requested and configured
>   user@domain.com merchant emails do not match.' in
>   /home/user/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Paypal/Model/Ipn.php:257

Based on my reading of the code:

- The "configured merchant email" comes from the Magento configuration
- The empty "Requested merchant email" comes from the receiver_email
  field in the PayPal IPN message.

Why would the IPN message have an empty receiver_email field?  I can make several guesses:

1. Protocol error from PayPal's service.
2. Configuration error in the PayPal.com account.
3. Magento bug resulting in empty or corrupt data.
4. Network problem resulting in empty or corrupt data.

Which is more likely, and how can I narrow it down?

---

It appears to be related to an adjustment transaction.  A few odd things:

1. The referenced order was paid by credit card, not Paypal Express.
2. The referenced order was adjusted months ago.
3. This latest transaction is missing from the order comment history.

I suspect this is a code or protocol error.  The transaction POST data is below with identifiers obscured to protect the innocent.

```
Array
(
    [txn_type] => adjustment
    [payment_date] => 12:17:03 Jul 20, 2015 PDT
    [payment_gross] => -64.45
    [mc_currency] => USD
    [verify_sign] => ...
    [payer_status] => verified
    [payer_email] => seller@address.com
    [txn_id] => ...
    [parent_txn_id] => ...
    [payer_id] => ...
    [invoice] => 123456789
    [reason_code] => chargeback_settlement
    [payment_status] => Completed
    [payment_fee] => -20.00
    [mc_gross] => -64.45
    [charset] => windows-1252
    [notify_version] => 3.8
    [ipn_track_id] => ...
)
```

Comment: Been a while for me (IPN)...What does, or do you have any way to obtain, the _original IPN_ message look like? IMHO that would narrow things down..

Comment: I will seek a way to obtain the original IPN message and follow-up later.

Comment: Edited post to include IPN message.

Comment: In Ipn.php. What is yours : getRequestData('business') ? getRequestData('receiver_email') ? _config->businessAccount OR paypal/general/business_account from core_config_data  ?

Comment: Answer is here magento.stackexchange.com/a/203672/44358

Answer (score 1):

In my case the issue was the configured email was not the primary email set on my paypal account. So, paypal was sending the default email account (which was different) as the requested email. After setting the configured email as the primary email address in paypal the issue seems to have been fixed.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a Magento bug. For chargebacks the merchant is actually the "payer". That is why in this case the address can be found in the `payer_email` field. The `_verifyOrder` method will have to be adjusted accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

In my case the error happened after changing the primary email in the PayPal admin panel.

When changing the primary email in PayPal you need to generate new API credentials since it looks like the credential are based on the primary email at the moment of its generation.

Once you remove the old API credentials and generate new ones, update the credentials in Magento (Stores > Configuration > Sales > Payment Methods > PayPal Express Checkout), flush the cache and the problem should be gone.